# How to reshape a ragged tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, ragged

Suppose you have stacked two sequences of 3-dimensional embeddings into a single ragged tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def foo(*args):
    n_elements = tf.reduce_prod(args)
    return tf.range(n_elements, dtype=tf.float32).reshape(args)

c = tf.ragged.stack((foo(2, 3), foo(5, 3)), axis=0)
assert c.shape == [2, None, None]
```

How to cast `c` to shape `[2, None, 3]` (because you know this tensor is of *this* shape)?

Comment: Did you try using `tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits`?

Comment: At some point I figured out that `RaggedTensors` are a completely unusable and unsupported feature of Tensorflow in their present state and dropped using them altogether. But thanks for your input.

`from_row_lengths` also works fine, btw

Comment: Hmm that is unfortunate..they can be sometimes tricky but are really useful actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits`:

```
tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits(
    values=c.merge_dims(0, 1).to_tensor(),
    row_splits=[0, 3, 7]).shape
```

```
(2, None, 3)
```